# Prove $0 < x < \pi /2 \implies \sin x > x/\sqrt{x^2+1}$ using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm solving the following problem:

> Show that if $0 < x < \pi /2$ then $\sin x > \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

One of the hints given is to apply mean value theorem for $\sin (x)$ on the interval $[0,x]$

This is my attempt so far:

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Since all trigonometric functions are continuous and $\sin (x)$ is differentiable, mean value theorem can be applied.

$$\frac{\sin x - \sin 0}{x - 0} = \cos c$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \cos c$$

We know that $0 < c < x$

So, $0 < c < x \leq \pi / 2$

So, $0 \leq \cos c < 1$

Also, $\cos c > \cos x$

$$\cos c > \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} > \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$$

$$\sin x > x\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$$

Now after this I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to bring $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ into the proof! I did think over it and was able to find some relations involving it like:

$$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} > 1$$

But I think I'm going the wrong path. How should I complete the proof ?

Comment: $$
\frac{\sin x} x = \cos c = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+\tan^2 c}} 
$$
but we cannot go on to say$\displaystyle {} > \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ unless we have $\tan c < x. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't think we have an assumption of $\tan c < x$. But I have attached the snapshot of the question from the book here: https://imgur.com/a/UHtGZGb
The question number is 12(b) and I hope I haven't missed anything.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
& \frac{\sin x} x = \cos c \\ {} \\
> {} & \cos x \text{ since the cosine function decreases on this interval} \\ {} \\
= {} & \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x} \\ {} \\
> {} & \sqrt{1-x^2} \text{ as shown in part (a) of the same exercise} \\{} \\
\not> {} & \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+x^2}}\quad \text{So this is not there yet.}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path: square both sides of $\sin(x)>x (1-\sin^2(x))^{1/2}$ and get $\sin^2(x)>x^2(1-\sin^2(x))=x^2-x^2\sin^2(x)$, then add $x^2\sin^2(x)$ to both sides to obtain $\sin^2(x)(1+x^2)>x^2$. Now divide both sides by $(1+x^2)$ and take the square root.

Comment: Can you expand on how squaring has given you $\sin^2(x)(1+x^2)>x$ ?

Comment: @Sibi, I think it's supposed to be an $x^2$ on the right hand side of the $\gt$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks! If that's the case, then do you where did the $(1 - sin^2(x))$ go from the RHS ?

Answer (score 0):

you've almost done it , just square both the sides and you'll find the factor you've been looking for